# Sending push on Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I need a liitle bit help. And here is my code :

```
               `ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("username", buddy);
                query.getFirstInBackground();

                ParseQuery q1=ParseInstallation.getQuery();
                q1.whereEqualTo("owner", query);

                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                push.setQuery(q1);
                push.setMessage("Hey its message");
                push.sendInBackground();`
```

But it does not work, owner is people who I want to send push. When I am saving `ParseUserName` to installation table on owner column.

Here is exception :

> javalang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class com.parse.ParseQuery

What's wrong here ?

Comment: Check at the parse website, is it sending this push or not? Go to the push notification of you app. Check the satus of the push, if it's status is "Succeed" press on this push and look the amount of pushes sent. And check the targeting of the push.

Comment: @MaxZavernutiy here is my exception :
javalang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class com.parse.ParseQuery

Comment: Also, do you want to send a push to a single user? If yes, than you are doing quite strange actions

Comment: yes , i wanna send only user. How can i do this whats your way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you want to send the push to a single user and you are saving ParseUserName to the installation table you can use this code.

```
            ParseQuery q1=ParseInstallation.getQuery();
            q1.whereEqualTo("owner", buddy);

            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            push.setQuery(q1);
            push.setMessage("Hey its message");
            push.sendInBackground();
```

Where buddy is a String with the ParseUserName